# Writing error data to new Bigquery table for GCP dataflow in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I am trying to build a dataflow job in python to write data from pubsub to Bigquery, the code is working fine but to handle errors and load them into new bigquery table i am having difficulty, can you please suggest a way to handle errors in run function and load the source message into a new table.

This function runs the dataflow pipeline and loads into bigquery table

```
  def run(argv=None):      
"""Build and run the pipeline."""

      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument(
          '--input_topic', dest='input_topic', required=True, 
          help='Input PubSub topic of the form "/topics/<PROJECT>/<TOPIC>".')
      parser.add_argument(
          '--output_table', dest='output_table', required=True, 
          help='Input the table name for bigquery".')
      parser.add_argument(
          '--output_dataset', dest='output_dataset', required=True, 
          help='Input the dataset name for bigquery".') 

      known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

      with beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args) as p:
        # Read from PubSub Topic 
        lines = p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(known_args.input_topic)
        #Adapt messages from PubSub to BQ table, this needs to be in JSON 
        lines = lines | beam.Map(parse_pubsub)
        #Write to a BQ table 
        lines | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=known_args.output_table,
                                        dataset=known_args.output_dataset,
                                        project='test-project',
                                        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
                                        )



    if __name__ == '__main__':
      logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
      run()
```

Comment: What problem are you having? It looks like you just took an online example and posted a question. Google has good tutorials for Dataflow. Go through a couple examples to get the concepts understood.

Comment: i need to handle the errors when parsing or writing into bq and load the errors and the actual message into a new table in bq, it is not an online example

Comment: Beam does not support what you want to do without a lot of effort as in copying/modifying beam source code yourself.

Comment: Are you in streaming or in batch pipeline? What is the reasons of the write error in bigquery?

Comment: Streaming data, i have the dataflow job working fine and loading the bq table, i wanted to think of scenarios when data from source is not good, wanted to ack that message and load them into a error table.